# Issue in reading array of file list in python

Tags: python, list, oop

I am trying to read files from a directory and then storing the same in `fileList` array.
Before this, I have done manually with doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4 and doc5 and then assigned the `doc_complete` the array of these five documents.
The code was working perfectly but when I have read the files from the directory now it is giving me following error:

```
File "D:/test/InvIndtest.py", line 26, in <module>
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

The Code is given below:-

```py
doc1 = "Sugar is bad to consume. My sister likes to have sugar, but not my father."
doc2 = "My father spends a lot of time driving my sister around to dance practice."
doc3 = "Doctors suggest that driving may cause increased stress and blood pressure."
doc4 = "Sometimes I feel pressure to perform well at school, but my father never seems to drive my sister to do better."
doc5 = "Health experts say that Sugar is not good for your lifestyle."
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('D:\\test\\text-files')
fileList = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for file in fileList:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        print ("Total Words in " + file[:10] + "= " + str(len(f.read())))
            words = f.read().lower().split()
    
            #compile documents
            doc_complete = fileList.append('')
            #doc_complete = [doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5]

print('\n\nData\n\n')
print(doc_complete)
    
# set of stopwords
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
exclude = set(string.punctuation) 
lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
    
def clean(doc):
    stop_free = " ".join([i for i in doc.lower().split() if i not in stop])
    punc_free = ''.join(ch for ch in stop_free if ch not in exclude)
    normalized = " ".join(lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in punc_free.split())
    return normalized
    
doc_clean = [clean(doc).split() for doc in doc_complete]    
    
    
print('\n\nCleaned Data\n\n')
print(doc_clean)
with open("doc_clean.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in doc_clean:
        f.write("%s\n" %doc_clean)
f.close()
```

Comment: you can print(fileList) after fileList = os.listdir(os.getcwd()) to figure out the problem

Comment: You are appending an empty string to `fileList` after each file.  It's not any of the original files in the list that are causing the problem, it's the first one of those empty strings.

Comment: Thank you very much. the qoutes in front of append were left unintentionally. I have now moved the doc_complete after the fileList=os.listdir and altered it as:- doc_complete = fileList.__getitem__.__name__. now its providing the names of files.